# Perl system access denied

Tags: perl, system

I'm running the following on a windows machine as an administrator

```
system("tracert 192.168.63.1 > d:\netmon\test.txt");
```

the output is Access Denied. Running the tracert without creating the file works fine. So Why can't I create the file in the existing netmon directory. I have full access to that directory.

Can somebody point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Does your command work at all if you run it from the command prompt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Perl, the backslash (`\`) is a special character inside of double quotes, used to "escape" other special characters or to specify other untypeable characters. The sequences `"\n"` and `"\t"`, which are contained in your example, are used to produce the newline and the tab character, respectively.

To produce a literal backslash character inside of double quotes, we use two consecutive backslash characters, so:

```
system("tracert 192.168.63.1 > d:\\netmon\\test.txt");
```

will produce the results you want.

Perl treats strings enclosed by single quotes (`''`) differently from double quotes. Inside single quotes, `\` is not a special character (well actually, it is still a little bit special, but a lot less special than inside double quotes), so you could also have written your expression as:

```
system('tracert 192.168.63.1 > d:\netmon\test.txt');
```

Comment: you can use '/' character in path. It doesn't matter you are working under linux or windows. universal '/' character separator is made for compatibility script between different systems. Alternatively you can change "..." to '....', and you will prevent using '\' as escape character. sometime you must insert any variable, you can do it with system(sprintf('tracert %s > %s',$ip_number_or_name,$path)); please don't remove brackets. othervise additional arguments will be assigned directly to system, not print function.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `\` in your path, you need to double up:

```
system("tracert 192.168.63.1 > d:\\netmon\\test.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use a slash instead:

```
 system('tracert 192.168.63.1 > d:/netmon/test.txt');
```

Comment: A filename in a `system`/`exec`/`qx` call is the one place where Perl can't automagically correct the path separator.

Comment: Or rather, a filename with IO redirection. `system("C:/path/to/Windows/executable.exe")` is OK, `system("program.exe > C:/path/to/Windows/file")` is not.

Comment: I thought / was legal in Windows natively? Or is this only Perl doing what I mean?